# Delete from SQLite Database

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an SQLite database linked up to my Java project within Eclipse. I'm able to delete entries from the database when I give a hardcoded, specified ID such as '3'. I'm trying to alter the code in order to enable the user the manually pass any number and have it delete that entry.

```
public static String deleteRecords(String NumberDelete){
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try{
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        String sql = "DELETE from employees where ID='NumberDelete';";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        dbConnection.commit();
        statement.close();
        dbConnection.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return NumberDelete;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For user input, you might want to check out the Scanner class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Once you get an integer from the user, parse it, and store it in a variable, you can simply use String concatenation:

```
String sql = "DELETE from employees where ID='" + userInput + "';";
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Knew it'd be a simple solution.

Comment: Do not string concatenate SQL queries; it opens up a risk of SQL injection. Use query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PreparedStatement` to pass the parameters to query and execute it, the method will look like this:

```
public static String deleteRecords(String NumberDelete) {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    String sql = "DELETE from employees where ID= ? ;";
    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, NumberDelete);
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        dbConnection.commit();
        statement.close();
        dbConnection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return NumberDelete;
}
```

This will set the number in the query and execute it. If the number is of type `int` then you need to use `setInt` to set the value. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is the javadoc for `PreparedStatement`.